# Sequential Loop Closing - SIMO

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I have studied *Sequential Loop Closing* or *SLC* in context of *MIMO* systems. Closing the loops sequentially while taking care of interactions make sense for a *square MIMO* systems. But does any theory exist for **SIMO** systems?

By **SIMO** systems I mean, underactuated system where you have more outputs than inputs, say the simplest case with $2$ outputs. In such a case combining the $2$ outputs to make a single output by some linear combination can be done but is restrictive. The question would be how can I analyze these restrictions?

In my particular case, I have two outputs and would like to design controller(s) that achieve a particular steady state response for the incoming input frequencies (i.e. required **Bode Plot** behavior). But for an underactuated system, I cannot do that independently using two controllers that are tuned independently. Is there a way to tune them together? Does a theory exit for that which limits the performance of these controller based upon which it can be commented if something is possible or not?

I can, in particular, give my exact control architecture but I think that would limit my understanding on a general level.

Comment: Good question. Could you clarify the SIMO system in more detail? You have a single input, 1 sensor/measurement signal? You have 1 reference signal? You have 1 error signal? As a result also a single controller? With that single controller you control two plants? Please give more details.

Comment: @WG The question is general...By this I mean that I have, lets say two outputs and one input, i.e. an underactuated system. Obviously I would have reference for the output signals, in this case two but I do not see how that would be relevant. In any case, I can intuitively imagine that for such a system, there would exist a lower dimensional subspace, governed by the constraints, according to which the solutions would evolve. This would put restrictions on the pair of values that you can achieve for the two outputs. I want to find out if theory exists for such cases which I assume would.

Comment: Sorry I was some what confused, misread the question. I thought you meant that your controller has only 1 input (measurement) and two outputs (two control signals), but it is the system of course (1 control signal, 2 measurements). However, LQR, LQG are techniques which you can employ to stabilize SIMO systems. However for them to work you will need a model of the system. A good example of a SIMO system is the cart which stabilzes a pendulum, see http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=InvertedPendulum&section=SystemModeling.

Comment: Thanks for the response...appreciate it...What I understand is that LQR and LQG are helpful if I know the relative importance of my states i.e. designing the penalty matrices...also it would not help me in shaping the frequency behavior i.e. BodePlot response

Comment: @Zero One possible solution is that to model the underactuated system in a descriptor system framework (allows you to add, additional 'constrained' states), so that you can still apply the SLC technique. Be aware, that  additional conditions are needed to guarantee stability.